# How to get from 0x all the different cryptos to add on sellToken and buyToken?

Tags: 0x

I'm trying to get all the crypto tokens available on 0x.

I've been reading all the docs but can't find in the API how to show all the crypto tokens available.

Does anyone know how to get that info?

I want to be able to make the request with all the different crypto pairs.

Appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0x API supports any token that follows ERC20 standard, that's why there is no need to have such list. You can use third party apis to fetch the most known ERC20 tokens, like coinmarketcap or coingecko.